# Solution For getting Mobile Number in Android

Tags: android

Using Telephony Manager returns null value for Mobile number, I want to get Mobile Number directly in to the app without asking user.

Comment: post your code when you got null value

Comment: TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);          String mobileNumber = tm.getLine1Number();    Here Iam getting mobileNumber as null

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TelephonyManager` to do this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

The `getLine1Number()` will return `null` if the number is "unavailable", but it does not say when the number might be unavailable.

You'll need to give your application permission to make this query by adding the following to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: yes, but I want Solution when the Number is not available

Answer (score 0):

Try the given below method for generating country code

```
  private void getCountryCode() {
        int code = 0;
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String CountryISO = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso().toString().toUpperCase();
        ;
        //String NetworkCountryIso = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toString();
        String number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
        code = getCountryCodeForRegion(CountryISO);
        Log.i("CountryISO", "CountryISO " + CountryISO);
        Log.i("code", "code " + code);
        Log.i("number ", "number " + number);


    }
```

Gets CountryCode from regionCode

```
public int getCountryCodeForRegion(String regionCode) {
    int result = -1;
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.android.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil");
        Method getInstance = c.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
        Method getCountryCodeForRegion = c.getDeclaredMethod("getCountryCodeForRegion", String.class);

        Object instance = getInstance.invoke(null);
        Integer code = (Integer) getCountryCodeForRegion.invoke(instance, regionCode);
        result = code;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to add permission in AndroidManifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```